# PHP: chr ( "0x03" ) generates error message why?

Tags: php

When I try to use chr ( "0x03" ) with PHP 7.1.15 I get an error message "A non well formed numeric value encountered", why do I get this message?

Comment: Because `chr` takes an integer and you are passing a string.

Comment: Use `chr(0x03)`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php